# TSQL - Find Customers who purchased two sets of Products

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with values like this:

```
Customer    Product#
   A           1
   A           3
   A           5
   A           7
   A           11
   A           13
   B           5
   B           11
   B           13
   C           4
   C           5
   C           6
   C           11
   C           14
   C           42
   C           60
```

I would like a query that will give me all customers who have:

```
a. Either Product# 1 OR 5
AND
b. BOTH Product# 11 AND 13.
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question downvoted so much? It's an interesting question, it's a tricky question, and clearly a tough one for a beginner. Haven't you downvoters all been at this point at some time?

Comment: @LukasEder I would guess because it shows no attempt at solving and it could be a post looking for a quick answer to a homework question.

Comment: @dfundako: Really? So what? [Agh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q37xJtuQ24w) :) Still an interesting question that got me thinking...

Comment: @dfundako: I had already solved the problem when I posted the question. I wanted to know if there was a more elegant solution. My working solution involves creating Table Variables for each of my data 'segments' [1. Customers with Product# 1 or 5, 2. Customers with Product# 11 AND 13] & inserting the appropriate data into them. Finally, I did a select on the Table Variables and got what I needed. I felt my way was simplistic [I don't think in sql :) ] & @ GurV 's answer provided an alternative that I could not have come up with. I didn't want to clutter my question with these details but ...

Comment: @dfundako: Additionally ... I [over?] simplified the data in order to make it easy to understand/answer. The actual data is a lot more complex and involves many more tables & joins but I just needed [and got from @GurV] the basic mechanics. Nonetheless, had this really been about getting homework done, would that have made it less worthy of an answer? Or ... are only esoteric, weird and wonderful sql conundrums worthy of posts? In the words of an ex-colleague, "The only dumb question is the one you didn't ask". :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
select customer
from your_table
group by customer
having count(distinct case 
            when product# in (11, 13)
                then product#
            end) = 2
    and count(case 
            when product# in (1, 5)
                then 1
            end) > 0
```

grouping by customer to find if both 11 and 13 are present, use conditional aggregation and similarly, check if there is atleast one row with 1 or 5 for the customer.

Answer (score 0):

'HAVING' works but you could also do this with a couple of subselects- longer and less efficient but easier to document and/or use with more complex outputs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a.customer
FROM 
     your_table AS a
WHERE 
     a.customer IN ( SELECT customer FROM your_table WHERE product# IN (1,5) )
     AND a.customer IN ( SELECT customer FROM your_table WHERE product# = 11)
     AND a.customer IN ( SELECT customer FROM your_table WHERE product# = 11)
```

Comment: Thanks @Franz Stoneking! Definitely easier to read. Appreciate it!